# Basic iOS browser code

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, browser, uiwebview

I need help. I am confused why my iOS Swift code doesn't work. I want to make a basic browser so that I put the address on the `textfield` and it appears on my `UIWebView`. but when iI push "run simulation" button, it brings me back to coding window. Anybody know why?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func urlField(sender: UITextField) {
        let url = NSURL(string:"http://facebook.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

}
```

Comment: your code is really confusing. Can you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic example.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    //when you press search button webView will search what you have entered into textField.
    @IBAction func Search(sender: AnyObject) {
        var text = textField.text
        var url = NSURL(string: text)
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.textField.delegate = self
    }
}
```

And when you type this in your textField: http://facebook.com

You will get this result:

[image]

Check [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=66410642611223316409) sample project for more Info.

Comment: Apple recommends  using `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`.

Comment: Fwiw, `File was deleted by owner or exceeded maximum storage time (100 days from last download).`